# Futter:Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 1)

Tags: flutter, sharedpreferences

```
void getUserData() async {
SharedPreferences pref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
var response = await http
    .get(Uri.parse("${baseURL + "/user/" + pref.getString('userToken')}"));
  setState(() {
  jsonData = jsonDecode(response.body);
  isLoading = false;
  print(jsonData['verified']);
});
```

Futter:Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 1)

Comment: can you first print response.body what you are getting into that ?

Comment: Perhaps you need to use `.body.toString()` like [here](https://www.androidbugfix.com/2022/02/flutter-unhandled-exception_18.html).